# How do I persist searched text in the SearchViews text field on search?

Tags: java, android

I have a `SearchView` in my action bar. When the user searches for a query and presses the "Go" button on keyboard, the search intent gets passed to my activity but the search field collapses and the query text is lost. How can I prevent this from happening? I would like the text to remain in the search field until explicitly cleared by the user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution turned out to be dead simple. Apparently, I wasn't setting the `android:launchMode` properly for the Activity. Ideally an activity that provides search functionality should be a single top so the user doesn't have to navigate backwards through all the previous searches upon clicking the "Back" button. Mine wasn't. Therefore, every time I searched, a new instance of my search activity was initiated and added to the view stack.

I added this to my manifest file under the correct activity.

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can store the search request either in a String variable or in the [shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) when the "Go" button is clicked by using getQuery() when the search event happends (setOnSearchClickListener) and then write them back in [either as the Query (setQuery) or as a hint (setQueryHint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html).

**Edit** (Based on the Question you can read below this answer)

How can you store the query string if the activity is recreated after every search? If you have some service that is persitent in the runtime of your aplication you could store it there, but that isn't that elegant. The easyest way to do it is to use the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). This is a persitant (key,value)-storage that you can use throughout your app to store and retreive values.

You initiate a SharedPreference with

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("mysharedprefenrences", 0);
```

The String can be anything you want. Whenever you use the same String to create a SharedPreferences-Object in your app, you will have acces to these values again.

To get a String, like your search query, use

```
String aString = prefs.getString("searchQuery", "")
```

with the second String being the default, if the query isn't set yet (in this case "").

When the setOnSearchClickListener is enacted you can store the Query by using an Editor.

```
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("searchQuery", queryString);
editor.commit();
```

Now the next time the activity is created, instead of the default String your stored String will be found.

Comment: HI Lukas, I added the method `onQueryTextChange` and `onQueryTextSubmit` to my Activity and used to the `SearchView.setOnSearchClickListener` to set the listener to `this`. I can get the event everytime the key is pressed and everytime the text is submitted but it seems that when a search is created, a new instance of my activity is created and I can't reference those same variables any more. Where should I write the `SearchView.getQuery()` method? Would you be able to provide some examples. I have been utterly lost with the search stuff. Thanks.